# Call to a member function find() on null CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to display all my data in a table name contacts but it gives me an error Call to a member function find() on null. I don't understand what it means. Please help!

```
<?php  
        class ContactsController extends AppController {
            var $name = "Contacts";

            public function index() {       
                $this->set('contacts', $this->Contacts->find('all'));
            }
        }
?>
```

Comment: write this instead. $this->Contact->find('all')

Comment: I guess you are using cakephp 2 so I added the appropriate tag

Answer (score 3):

In your controller.

```
<?php  
    class ContactsController extends AppController {
        public function index() {
            $this->set('contacts', $this->Contact->find('all'));  // here the change Contacts to Contact.
        }
    }
?>
```

Your Model.

```
<?php  
    class Contact extends AppModel {
        var $name = "Contact";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller use the variable $use as follows

```
$use = array ('model_name');
```

Only that

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the below code in the header section in your `controller`

```
public $uses = array('Your_Model_Name');  // array('User');
```